# Visual Studio Extensions for Windows Library for JavaScript version 2.1.30324.52 seems stuck at "Configuring your system. This might take a while."

Tags: windows, visual-studio-2013, javascript, visual-studio-extensions

I'm wondering if the installer is hung up on something, and if there's any way around this issue but today I went to upgrade this extension to the latest, and its been in the following state for the past half hour to an hour now, on a pretty quick machine (I've had this same installation finish in under ten minutes on a much slower machine than the one I'm trying to install it in now):

[image]

Is this normal? Has anyone experienced something similar? What is it trying to do in the background, because as it says, "This might take awhile." throws me off since my "while" might be a lot different than Microsoft's "while", and at what point would you consider cancelling the installation?

I'm running Visual Studio 2013 on Windows 8.1 Pro x64. All other extensions are installed and up to date.

Comment: Mine took a while, but it did eventually install.  This was the case on two different machines; both of which were i5s I am running the same Studio configuration as you.

Comment: Still waiting? I have seen these issues a lot when running with a network attached user folder.

Comment: Running 2013 myself, but this kind of installation problems isn't uncommon to me. Although they tend to be very hard to analyze.

Comment: You guys were right, it did finish afterall...it only took about 6 hours...

Comment: What are your system specs?

Comment: @NeilMonroe 8GB RAM, Windows 8.1 Enterprise x64 (whoops, forgot it was actually Enterprise and not Pro on this machine; I got that wrong in the question), and Core i7.

Comment: Not sure what was going on, but that sounds like an acceptable system setup. Are you short on disk space at all or installing over the network?

Answer (score 3):

Mine installed, but VS2013 still lists it as a needed update which annoys me.  If I go to install it again, it gives repair or uninstall options, so I know it got installed.

Comment: I had that too. Try checking the installed packaged with the Windows command wmic product get and pipe it into a file. Then, you gotta uninstall one of the installed 2.0 versions using msiexec /x{GUID}

Comment: Alexandru, I'll give that a go.  It is very annoying, and should be logged as a bug.

Answer (score 0):

In the end it completed after a handful (~6) of hours and productivity was lost because it kept kicking off installers for all of the Visual Studio's on my machine.

Answer (score 0):

So, after having to experience this heartache for a second time, I was inspired to clear out and watch my `C:\Users\{username}\AppData\Local\Temp` directory to see what kind of log files are produced.

***In two hours time it created 360 files that occupied 642MB of space.***

Judging by the types of log files it's producing, it looks like not only did it uninstall the previous version of itself but it also reapplied the VS2012.4 Update as well as the VS2013.2RC Update.  What the justification is for that, the world may never know, but at least you know why it takes so long.

Hope that helps...

Comment: Yeah, I noticed that too...and if you have multiple Visual Studio versions installed, you're gonna be in for even more of a world of hurt.

Answer (score 0):

Use task manager to close the installer. Find Visual Studio in apps list and run it. It may say "It cannot run when setup is running" as it did for me. In that case make a new windows local account or use an existing one. And open Visual Studio. It shall run and ask you to sign it meaning its installed...
Try checking it in your own account it would start running as well... well at least it did for me.

If it still didn't work try restarting your PC.

PS Use task manager only when its done downloading and starts configuring your system.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and it was due to one of the sub-installers launched by the main installer being stuck.  Here's how I resurrected the install:

[Visual Studio Express 2013 for windows with update 2 installation Taking Too much time in "Configuring Your System"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24386051/visual-studio-express-2013-for-windows-with-update-2-installation-taking-too-muc/26080325#26080325)