# Visual Studio Express 2013 for windows with update 2 installation Taking Too much time in "Configuring Your System"

Tags: windows, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

visual studio express 2013 for web is already installed on my windows 8.1 laptop.

Now i am trying to install **visual studio express 2013 for widows with update 2.**

It works fine until last step , but in last step **"Configuring Your System, this may take a white" . it just goes like infinite loop. it just showing installing and progress**

it has takes **more than 3 hours and still same progress**.

after i have decided to cancel the setup, but same problem in cancelling , just goes on and on.

after that i have killed the process from task manager. and then restarted the Laptop.

but **after Restart the setup is started from where it left.  and still the same issue.**

Please Someone help.

either i want to cancel the setup, or to install successful. but nothing works its just goes like infinite loop.

any idea how can i do this?

Answer (score 13):

I had the same problem today trying to install Visual Studio 2013 Update 3 from the 6.9 GB iso file I downloaded from MSDN.  A few things:

1) First I stopped then disabled the Windows Search process since it seemed to be in a fight for the disk during the install.  Note, disabling the service is not enough since something keeps turning back on.  You have to right click on the service entry in the Task Manager Services tab and then choose Open Services option since trying to end the task directly from the tab will fail.  From the Open Services option you can stop the Windows Search service and then change it's run status to *disabled*.  Don't forget to turn it back on later when you're done with the install.

2) I looked in my Task List and I noticed there were some entries for the installer for Visual Studio 2013 RC 2.  I had uninstalled that version because the design editor was crashing continuously.  The uninstall was only partially successful.  I wonder if it got launched in an attempt to clean up the previous uninstall.  In either case, I ended the task for RC 2.

3) I also saw entries for the Windows Phone 8.1 emulator installers.  I ended those tasks too.

The instant I did steps #2 and #3 the main Visual Studio installer perked up and said Setup Completed.  My guess is that either the RC 2 installer or the Windows Phone 8.1 emulator installer got stuck and the main installer was waiting for it to return.  I then clicked LAUNCH and Visual Studio 2013 Update 3 started properly.  The good news is that the update worked fine.

The moral of the story is if you get the problem reported by the original poster, check for *stuck* sub-installers in your task list and get rid of them, but do *not* stop the main installer.

Comment: That's it! I killed all related process (mine was "Mobile Tools") and it worked.

Comment: Weired, killed the processes and it worked like a charm

Answer (score 7):

I've got similar issue. I solve it by going to process manager and killing all visual studio application process (i.e. emulator, visual studio 32b, visual studio for web...) without main process of instalation. After 5 minutes installation end.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem with Visual Studio 2014 Update 3 hanging for hours at the very end of the install. The very second I ended the process described by Robert Oscler at (3) above "I also saw entries for the Windows Phone 8.1 emulator installers. I ended those tasks too." the install finished and I was ready to launch.  This really worked thanks. If your not familiar with Task Manager here's what to do. To do it you press CTRL ALT DELETE together and pick Task Manager. If there is nothing showing press More Details bottom right. On the processes page scroll down until you see an entry that has Windows Phone 8.1 emulator (or similar) as a description. Click on any of these and just press the button that says end task on the bottom right. You need to be careful what processes that you end in general but it's fine to end Windows Phone 8.1 emulator in this case.  Hope this fixes the problem for you and thanks again to Robert

Answer (score 1):

I had Visual Studio 2013 Ultimate on my laptop and downloaded and installed VS 2013 with Update 2 on the same machine.

I got to that last step "`Configuring Your System, this may take a while`" and it took like forever. About 2 hours for me.

My take is that you wait for it to complete, maybe leave it finishing up overnight.

Another suggestion, assuming you installed "over" the original VS 2013 is to first uninstall it and the install VS 2013 with Update 2.